# How do I create a channel access token for LINE (messaging app in Japan), to use with their API?

Tags: python, api, token, messaging, line-api

I'm trying to use the LINE API. I am following [these github instructions](https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-python) and just need to create a 'Channel Access Token' and 'Channel Secret'.

```
line_bot_api = LineBotApi('YOUR_CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN')
handler = WebhookHandler('YOUR_CHANNEL_SECRET')
```

The main issue I am having is that the docs pages are out of date, and I can't find out how to enable the API for my business account:
https://developers.line.me/messaging-api/getting-started#apply_messagingapi
The 'bot API' section no longer exists anywhere on any of the categories on the left.

**Documentation links**

[link #1 to devdocs API page](https://devdocs.line.me/en/)

[link #2 to developers page](https://developers.line.me/)

[link #3 getting started guide](https://developers.line.me/messaging-api/getting-started) (i have a business account)

Answer (score -1):

From the Line docs:

> To respond to messages from your users using the Messaging API, you
>   first need to enable webhooks for your LINE@ account on the LINE@
>   Manager. You’ll then need to get a Channel access token and set a
>   webhook URL on the Channel Console.

Comment: thank you Kai! I have enabled webhooks already. How do I get the Channel access token?

Comment: Per the documentation, it looks like that should be found on the channel console

Comment: Here is all I see: http://imgur.com/10XCqxJ And then this: http://imgur.com/a/IfsWY

Comment: Kai, the channel console looks like this: http://imgur.com/a/2F5L5 But it doesn't give me a token

Comment: You enabled the API?

Comment: Yup! I did. It almost feels like the UI of my admin page is missing something